# How to express the idea of being somewhere

Tags: grammar, words

So I've been searching the internet and I can't find my answers because all it says is the N5 imasu/arimasu I don't think it's right.

So the context is like "imagine, you are in a place where blah blah"

I can't find any JP lessons in the internet that covers this certain kind of existence other than imasu and arimasu. Pls help thanks!

Comment: Why don't you think imasu/arimasu is right?

Comment: "imasu" and "arimasu" probably could not be used as is in such a sentence, but not because of the meaning, more because they'd probably need to be in another form besides the -masu ending. For example, iru/ita.

Comment: I thought there's something wrong in my sentence when I used it. So to give u an idea on what it's like, it goes like "imagine u are in a place where everybody is safe".. My intial thought was "anata ga minasan wa anzen da .... Basho ni iru to souzou shite kudasai" so I really thought there's something wrong in there I just couldn't find exactly the right lesson for this grammar point.

Comment: So i think I came up with a more sensible one???

Imagine you are in a place where everybody is safe - Minasan wa anzen da to iu koto ga basho ni iru to souzou shite kudasai -  皆さんは安全だということが場所にいると想像してください。

Please let me know if I'm going the right path here lol :D I'm only self studying and I don't exactly know in JP lessons where is this chapter being talked on? thanks!

Comment: What you need to learn seems to be how to say the “a place where …” part. It has little to do with いる or ある. Indeed you are using いる correctly in your sentences. I would suggest you edit your question (including the title) so what you are asking will be clearer.